# SQL - Multiple request in only one

Tags: sql

I have a table called eod, and there is a sample of it.

```
| eod_id | company_symbol |    date    | open  | close | high  |  low  |
|      1 |            AAA | 01-01-2000 | 40.00 | 42.00 | 43.00 | 39.00 |
```

For a given company_symbol, I want to:

1. Calculate (open for a date)/(close for an other date) - 1
2. Count the rows where open > close
3. Count the rows where open < close
4. For each day, number of times where the company_symbol has the highest close
5. For each day, number of times where the company_symbol has the
   lowest close

I tried to get the informations I want, but I didn't succeed.
Is it possible to get the 5 informations in only one request ?

Hope you could help me,
Thanks,

Steve

PS : What I tried :

1.

```
SELECT (SELECT OPEN FROM eod WHERE company_symbol="AAPL" AND DATE="2013-04-05") 
/ (SELECT OPEN FROM eod WHERE company_symbol="AAPL" AND DATE="2000-01-03") - 1;
```

2.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eod WHERE company_symbol="AAPL" AND CLOSE>OPEN;
```

3.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eod WHERE company_symbol="AAPL" AND CLOSE<OPEN;
```

1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EOD WHERE company_symbol IN (SELECT company_symbol FROM eod
   WHERE CLOSE IN (SELECT max(CLOSE) FROM eod GROUP BY DATE));

But this one doesn't work, could you help me with this ?
I also think those requests can be simplified, but I don't know how to.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so we can point to any potential corrections

Comment: I added it in my first post

Answer (score 0):

If you need just group "5 informations in only one request", try to make 5 requests for what you want, then just

```
SELECT  
(%your_request1%) as 'Request 1',  
(%your_request2%) as 'Request 2',  
(%your_request3%) as 'Request 3',  
(%your_request4%) as 'Request 4',  
(%your_request5%) as 'Request 5'  
FROM EOD e  
WHERE company_symbol=AAA
```

or you also need this 5 requests?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to group the 5 requests, but by doing like this, I'm going to read 5 times the table. I'd like to read the table once, in order to increase performance. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you realy need this performance increasing? Are you running this query for %a_lot% times and got lack of performance?

Comment: I added the request I have make in my first post. The are around 1.5 millions of rows in the table, and one request takes about 2 sec. Could you help me simplifying my requests please?